# concatenate fields from array of Java objects

Tags: java, arrays, string, object, field

I am a newbie to Java. I have an array of objects that have a string field. I can concatenate all of the strings into an string array by looping, but it's very inelegant.

```
int numObj = obj.length;
String[] strArray = new String[numObj];
for (int i = 0; i < numObj; i++) {
    strArray[i] = obj[i].strField;
}
```

Is there a way to concatenate that single field from all of the objects into a string array in one command? e.g.:

```
String[] strArray = (String[]){obj[].strField};
```

This doesn't work because `obj[]` is an array and so it doesn't have any fields, but using `{obj.strField}` doesn't work either, because there is no object called `obj`. BTW I really don't have to recast the field or do `.toString()` because it is already a string.

I looked at many, many of the other posts (but perhaps not enough?) related to this but I still could not figure this out. There are some that refer to converting an object array to a string array, but I don't think those posts mean converting a particular field in the objects, but the object itself, as an uncast type.

In MATLAB this would be trivial: `strCellArray = {obj.strField};` would create a cell array of strings from all of the strFields in `obj` instantly.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry, you pretty much have to do the loop.  This is an area where Java is a bit inelegant compared to some other languages.  Java 8 or 9 or 10 may fix this.  :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you did is the only way. You don't have to create a variable for the length of the array, though. And using public fields is, 99.99% of the times, a very bad idea:

```
String[] strings = new String[objects.length];
for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    strings[i] = objects[i].getStringField();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on keeping fields private.